# reading stream with right encoding in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a stream with iso-8859-1 encoding with C#:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream,System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
  var current_enc = reader.CurrentEncoding; //value is UTF8
```

i set the encoding with iso-8859-1 but it's not really set after.
Some one has seen this behaviour?

Comment: From the docs: "The StreamReader object attempts to detect the encoding by looking at the first three bytes of the stream. It automatically recognizes UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text if the file starts with the appropriate byte order marks. **Otherwise**, the user-provided encoding is used. " - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456.aspx

Comment: Your example works for me. Have you verified that `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` returns a non-null value? May be latin1 is (for some strange reason) not availiable?

Comment: Ok, you're right that the working is not obvious, the first ctor behaves as if `true` was passed to the second.

Answer (score 0):

I find a parameter of StreamReader detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks.
If it is to false, there isn't detect encoding and take yours.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream,System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), false))
```